# How to enable missing system UI notification icons?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-icons, miui

Is there a way to fix missing notifications icons on MIUI, on MIUI 9 there is no toggle symbol for VPN **activated** like WiFi or Bluetooth. I need a convenient way to confirm whether the VPN is running or not.

On stock Android, an active VPN connection is indicated by a "key" icon but on on MIUI 9. Is there a way or fix to make sure the icon appears, other thanconstantly looking on the shade to confirm if the VPN is still active

Comment: Is it the same even if you switch VPN?

Comment: @beeshyams yes even when the vpn is on

Comment: I meant if you change the VPN provider, is the icon still missing. [As an example](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/issues/588) related to a particular VPN provider (includes MIUI)

Comment: @beeshyams yes even when I change the provider nothing displays